# play2.1.* java what kind of functionality must be implemented via plugins and why

Tags: java, jpa, playframework, playframework-2.0

During the using of Play2 java, I have a question in my head always that why we should use play plugin to make play support more feature on play? like DB, JPA, Mailer. The document only gives a simplest sample to show how to write a plugin, there is no words about why.
Because if I do not know the root cause I can not know when I should write a plugin or just write a util class.

I already know that if you want to utilize some life cycle of play you can use plugin is better etc, but this is too general, can some one give me a concrete sample?

And After I tested, 
1,JPA only can implemented by plugins, if I use pojo to write the same code as in the JPAPlugins it will raise the exception which can not find my model classes.
2,Mailer it's working well just add dependencies and write pojo to send email instead of mailer plugin.

So my question is what kind of functionality must be implemented via plugins and why? thanks a lot.
it confused me a long time, let me know if the question description is not clear, thanks..

Comment: A plugin is a design pattern to make code reuse easy, nothing 'must' be implemented via a plugin.
As a rule of thumb, if you have to do something once: put it in the project code; twice (in the same project): encapsulate it in a utility; twice (in different projects): make it a project plugin.

Comment: Not that easily, like what I described there, JPAPlugins only work via plugins, the Mailer is working fine via normal pojo.
I found the classloader which load the project code which I wrote is different with the one load the plugin or jar, but looks they can communicate, I want to know how does the two classloaders communicate.

Comment: Ok, I don't immediately have an answer. I think I understand what you are asking, but only after finding your conversation on the [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/2wzxBQL_Tvo/discussion) IMHO, it would have been helpful to link to that from your question since it contains a possible partial solution that you are trying to build upon here.